# clearCachedResult() not working as expected

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have this query located in my ParseQueryBuilder object:

```
public ParseQuery<Event> eventsTypes() {
    ParseQuery<Event> query = Event.getQuery();
    query.setCachePolicy(ParseQuery.CachePolicy.CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    query.setMaxCacheAge(TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1));
    query.whereEqualTo(Event.owner, parse.getParseUser());
    query.orderByDescending(Event.timesUsed);
    return query;
}
```

I use it to populate a ParseQueryAdapter
and at some point I would like to add an Event and immediately show it:

```
@OnClick(R.id.add)
public void add(Button button) {
    final Event new_type = new Event();
    new_type.setOwner(parse.getParseUser());
    new_type.setName("atest");
    new_type.saveEventually(new SaveCallback() {

        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // on successfull save, clear cache
                parseQueryBuilder.eventsTypes().clearCachedResult();
                // and show newly added object
                mAdapter.loadObjects();

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), new_type.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I expected clearing the cache would result in a new network query, revealing the newly added item but no matter what I try, it seems it will only show the initially cached result.

Even if I try to restart my app, it shows the result from the first cache.